# I want to make a share short video app for ios

Tags: swift, xcode

I want Making an application that works with FireBase.The application will be like this .
User profiles will be.
You can add friends.
You can uploads max 20 seconds videos.
How can i do this ?
Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend taking a look at these links

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/

Firebase has very good tutorials in getting you started with their database.
Good luck :)